# Why Is Pagination Not Displaying Data?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my codes counting OK results, the total count when I echo but trying to print out data it just won't show anything.

### My code is:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recent WHERE memberID = '".$uid."'";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
$stmt->execute();

global $per_page;

$total = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$pages = ceil($total / $per_page);

$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
'options' => array(
'default'   => 1,
'min_range' => 1,
),
)));

$offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM recent WHERE memberID = '".$uid."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :per_page OFFSET :offset";
$stmt->bindParam(':per_page', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: try echo $total['COUNT(*)']  after fetchColumn().

Comment: i get this printed SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recent WHERE memberID = '10'

Comment: Since `$uid` is injected into the raw query (rather than being passed as parameter like `per_page` and `offset`) the final SQL can be valid or not (it's impossible to say). Unless you configure PDO to throw exceptions explicitly, invalid SQL may go unnoticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your database connection with

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=yourdatabasename;','username','password');
?>
```

Then use prepare

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute( array($uid) );

global $per_page;

$total = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$pages = ceil($total / $per_page);

$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
'options' => array(
'default'   => 1,
'min_range' => 1,
),
)));

$offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$uid."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :per_page OFFSET :offset";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':per_page', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: after that now i get this error 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031

Comment: You cannot use ->bind* and ->execute($params). Use either or; if you pass parameters to execute(), those will make PDO forget the parameters already bound via ->bind*.